# Parts of an SVG will not change color on hover?

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

I have set up a simple color-change hover for an SVG object, however, the center part of the SVG will not change color on hover, only the outer part of the SVG changes. Any suggestions or clues to get the entire SVG to change color on hover?

I've also set up a CodePen here: http://codepen.io/codebuddy/pen/HlmuE

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I'd like the outer ring and inner arrow to change color, with the negative space.

Comment: Like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Crkhm

Comment: Awesome, yes! I'll have to look over what you did so I fix this moving forward. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give the `polygon` arrow element a class (`.inner_arrow`) and then use the following:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryKim)

```
.arrow, .arrow-group path,
.inner_arrow {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.arrow:hover .arrow-group path,
.arrow:hover .inner_arrow {
  fill: red;
}
```